# Why my app info empty about Draw, Process, Execute adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo

Tags: shell, adb, frame-rate, dumpsys

1. I Used, adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo

Why my app info empty  about Draw, Process, Execute adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo?
I dont understand why empty that stats.
Help me pls.

```
** Graphics info for pid 3213 [com.kabam.marvelbattle] **

Recent DisplayList operations
  Save
  ClipRect
  DrawDisplayList
    DrawPatch
    Save
    ClipRect
    Translate
    DrawPatch
    DrawDisplayList
      DrawText
    RestoreToCount
  DrawDisplayList
  RestoreToCount
DrawRect
DrawPatch
DrawPatch
DrawText
DrawDisplayList
  DrawDisplayList
    DrawDisplayList
      DrawRect
      Save
  ClipRect
  DrawDisplayList
    DrawPatch
    Save
    ClipRect
    Translate
    DrawPatch
    DrawDisplayList
      DrawRect
      DrawText
    RestoreToCount
  DrawDisplayList
  RestoreToCount
DrawRect
DrawPatch
DrawPatch
DrawRect
DrawText
SetupShader
DrawRect
ResetShader
DrawDisplayList
  DrawDisplayList
DrawDisplayList
  DrawDisplayList
    DrawColor
DrawRect
DrawColor

Caches:
Current memory usage / total memory usage (bytes):
  TextureCache            30052 / 75497472
  LayerCache                  0 / 50331648
  RenderBufferCache           0 /  8388608
  GradientCache               0 /  1048576
  PathCache                   0 / 33554432
  TextDropShadowCache         0 /  6291456
  PatchCache                768 /   131072
  FontRenderer 0 A8     1048576 /  1048576
  FontRenderer 0 RGBA         0 /        0
  FontRenderer 0 total  1048576 /  1048576
Other:
 FboCache                    0 /       16
Total memory usage:
  1079396 bytes, 1.03 MB

Profile data in ms:
com.kabam.marvelbattle/com.explodingbarrel.Activity/android.view.ViewRootImpl@41a7df30
    Draw    Process Execute

View hierarchy:

  com.kabam.marvelbattle/com.explodingbarrel.Activity/android.view.ViewRootImpl@41a7df30
```

6 views, 0.22 kB of display lists, 5 frames rendered

```
Total ViewRootImpl: 1
Total Views:        6
Total DisplayList:  0.22 kB
```

Comment: Need to add HWUI tag here

Answer (score 0):

In the AOSP exists several approaches how to render UI:

- based on CPU library such as SKIA
- based on HW accelerated library - such as HWUI

For the above log, output means - your Activity does not use accelerated HWUI -  there is no allocated [HardwareRenderer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e40462e11d27eb859b829b112cecb8c6f0d7afb/core/java/android/view/HardwareRenderer.java) implementation to your Activity's Views.
The **dumpGfxInfo() API** implementation has nothing to output here - see the [sources](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java#497)

Here is relevant question [How to enable skia with GPU backend on JB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285782/how-to-enable-skia-with-gpu-backend-on-jb/15305941) - to enable HWUI utilization